# PDFbox to iText coordinate conversions using AffineTransform

Tags: java, awt, itext, pdfbox, affinetransform

### Question:

I can't seem to get one coordinate format to work with another format. I think I'm just not using the right matrix, but I don't know enough about them to be certain.  I was hoping to get some help figuring out if I'm making an assumption on what my transform should be.

iText uses the bottom left as origin per ISO standard, but the pdfbox code and the program that gives me the coordinates to scrape from the pdf both use the upper left as the origin.

What transform should I be doing to adapt the coordinates so that iText can consume them in a way that will work?

### Background

I've got some code that uses pdfbox to manipulate a pdf and strip out some data and now I need to inject the modified data back on the page.  PDFBox's writer keeps corrupting the pdf so we have decided to go with iText to do the injection.

The trick is that the coordinates I used with pdfbox (and the ones we get from the system generating the pdf) don't seem to match up with iText's.

### What I've done so far

I checked, and both the iText page and cropbox seem to be accurate:

```
  PdfReader splitPDFDocumentReader = new PdfReader(splitPDFdocumentName);

  com.lowagie.text.Rectangle theCropBox = splitPDFDocumentReader.getCropBox(1);
  com.lowagie.text.Rectangle thePageSize = splitPDFDocumentReader.getPageSize(1);

  consolePrintln("Cropbox: " + theCropBox.toString());
  consolePrintln("\tBottom " + theCropBox.getBottom());
  consolePrintln("\tLeft " + theCropBox.getLeft());
  consolePrintln("\tTop " + theCropBox.getTop());
  consolePrintln("\tRight " + theCropBox.getRight());

  consolePrintln("PageSize: " + thePageSize.toString());
  consolePrintln("\tBottom " + thePageSize.getBottom());
  consolePrintln("\tLeft " + thePageSize.getLeft());
  consolePrintln("\tTop " + thePageSize.getTop());
  consolePrintln("\tRight " + thePageSize.getRight());
```

Outputs:

```
Cropbox: Rectangle: 612.0x792.0 (rot: 0 degrees)
    Bottom 0.0
    Left 0.0
    Top 792.0
    Right 612.0
PageSize: Rectangle: 612.0x792.0 (rot: 0 degrees)
    Bottom 0.0
    Left 0.0
    Top 792.0
    Right 612.0
```

Which would lead me to believe its just a matter of flipping the y coordinate since pdfbox's origin is in the top left, whereas iTexts is in the bottom left.

### Where I run into trouble

When I apply the transform:

```
  //  matrix data example:
  //  [m00, m01, m02,
  //   m10, m11, m12,
  //   0  , 0  , 1   ]  // this bit is implied as part of affineTransform docs
  content.saveState();
  int m00 = 1;
  int m01 = 0;
  int m02 = 0;
  int m10 = 0;
  int m11 = -1;
  int m12 = 0;

  content.concatCTM(m00, m10, m01, m11, m02, m12);

  content.setColorStroke(Color.RED);
  content.setColorFill(Color.white);
  content.rectangle(x, y, x + height, y + width);
  content.fillStroke();

  content.restoreState();
```

It doesn't seem to do what I would expect. It seems that the data is completely outside the page.

### Misc notes

To be honest, i'm not very good with matrixes, perhaps I need to do some translation work and not just filp the y as I've tried to do?

The concatCTM function seems to take the same format as [awt.geom.affinetransform](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html#AffineTransform%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20double%29), and I am going by [this example](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=243) and [tutorial](http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/overview-of-the-graphics-state-methods-part-2-itext-5/) for using the transforms.

Comment: iText uses the coordinate system as defined in ISO-32000-1. If the coordinate system is different in PDFBox, they're using a custom transformation. You're right about Transformation Matrix: the way the CTM works is slightly different from the algebra we were taught at high school. In high school we used matrices to transform object; in PDF the matrix is used to transform the coordinate system. That nuance leads to different results. You may find it easier to change your coordinates (as taught in high school) rather than to change the CTM (as explained in ISO-32000-1). Also: please upgrade.

Comment: I'm assuming its just like how you manipulate objects in openGL/directX, or something like Processing's transform primitives.  I think I might just have the transform wrong.

I thought that flipping on the Y axis would be the same as rotating 180* and filping over the X. I'll keep playing around.

What are you referring to when you say upgrade?

Comment: Regarding the upgrade, I see that you're using my name in your code. Please read http://lowagie.com/itext2

Comment: The argument your attorney uses strikes me as being a scare tactic... Anything *MAY* have infringing content. We could be just as liable for the latest version under agpl (or a paid license) as we were with the earlier one, or for using anything licensed LGPL like hibernate. The argument is basically saying that we shouldn't use any 3rd party code regardless of the license.

Comment: What assurances can we have that your codebase still doesn't have bad code? I haven't read any change logs regarding the source code cleanup, and that post you have was written seemed to have been penned 2y8mo after the release of 5.0. That one article is the only reference to this issue I can find. Have you contracted a source code audit through a 3rd party that we can refer to? Did they find bad things?

Comment: I think we are stuck with using whatever version Jasper iReports uses internally for compatibility reasons. if this is really a big concern, we may need to look at a different provider and contact their legal team. What is the best way to get in touch with someone behind itext?

Comment: For the IP review, see this old presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/blowagie/itext-ip-review To get in touch with somebody at iText: http://itextpdf.com/sales

Comment: Fascinating, thank you for the presentation.  That last slide refers to 2007. Were there more changes between that date and the 2009 release that we wouldn't have concerning possible liability? I find it strange that Jasper reports is still on 2.1.7 despite of this.

Comment: There was a second IP review in 2011. Since the initial IP review, we have the discipline to document all new contributions. Contributors from outside the iText group sign a Contributor License Agreement.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. When I was fipping the y coordinate, I was assuming it would flip over the middle of the document and just invert everything. However it actually flips over the line y=0;

After it flips over y=0, you would need to shift the entire page back up.

I ended up using affineTransform directly to get it done, then just feed the resulting matrix into concatCTM.

```
content.saveState();

AffineTransform transform = new AffineTransform();

transform.scale(1, -1); // flip along the line y=0
transform.translate(0, -pageHeight); // move the page conet back up

/* the version of iText used in Jasper iReport doesn't seem to use affineTransform directly */
double[] transformMatrix = new double[6];
transform.getMatrix(transformMatrix);

content.concatCTM((float) transformMatrix[0], (float) transformMatrix[1], (float) transformMatrix[2], (float) transformMatrix[3], (float) transformMatrix[4], (float) transformMatrix[5]);

// drawing and printing code here (stamping?)

content.restoreState();
```

Comment: Yes, the translate was missing in your initial transformation.

Comment: And now the text is writing upside down...  Yay more transforms.

Thanks for taking the time to review things.  I put in a request to order the second edition of your book - it seems there are a lot of improvements and would be worth updating even if we have to pay some fees.

Comment: I've started writing a third edition. I'll make it available for free, but... I've only started writing last Tuesday and I'm only at 17 pages. As for the latest releases: yes, plenty of functionality has been added.

Comment: Concerning *And now the text is writing upside down...* If you don't want that to happen, you might just use the translation transformation and not the one flipping along y=0. This gives you a coordinate system with the origin up left but *negative* y coordinates in the page area. To use the coordinates from those other programs, you then merely need to change the sign of the y ccordinates. Without the flipping transformation the text will not render upside down anymore...